# Getting error while using eclipselink moxy as default jaxb impl provider with spring + camel. Works with Jaxb-RI

Tags: spring, eclipselink, apache-camel, moxy

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [camel-context.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/web-application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:

[java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1423)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.(JAXBContext.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

**Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:2429)**
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:904)

This is while trying with eclipseelink 2.5.1-SNAPSHOT version to overcome https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411993.

Comment: Could you provide some details about the domain model you are using?

Comment: The problem is not with my domains - I'm facing problem with spring-camel models  org.apache.camel.core.xml.util.jsse.AbstractSSLContextParametersFactoryBean
org.apache.camel.core.xml.util.jsse.AbstractSSLContextClientParametersFactoryBean
org.apache.camel.core.xml.util.jsse.AbstractSSLContextServerParametersFactoryBean
org.apache.camel.core.xml.util.jsse.AbstractBaseSSLContextParametersFactoryBean

I did extend the "if (descriptor != null) {...}" block and tried in  org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings() - and seems to work.

Comment: Are you interacting with MOXy JAXB directly?  I'm trying to piece together a test case I can use to reproduce the exception you are seeing.

Comment: No, I'm not interacting directly. 

I have also posted here
http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/Possibly-bug-getting-NullPointerException-org-eclipse-persistence-jaxb-compiler-MappingsGenerator-ge-td162364.html

- changing the same seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**:  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**UPDATE**

I have checked in a fix for this issue to the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  You will be able to download a nightly build with this fix starting August 24, 2013 from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

I have opened the following bug that you can use to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/415785

Comment: Is there a workaround for this issue? Can I add some annotations on my model so that I don't run into this? Or is the upgrade to 2.5.1 mandatory? The weird thing is that this issue only happens for me when serializing to Json and not when serializing to XML.